# Que significa el comando git log origin..HEAD?

Tags: git

Alguien podría explicarme qué hace o significa el resultado mostrado por el comando lanzado desde mi rama en local

```
git log origin..HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Muestra la lista de commits que hay desde el último commit realizado (apuntado por HEAD) hasta el último commit en la rama `origin` (que es una rama oculta que contiene lo último que hayas bajado con PULL desde un remoto).

Si no te encuentras en una situación de *detached head*, (es decir, si HEAD no está apuntando a algún commit intermedio, sino realmente al último commit de la rama) ese comando te mostraría los commits que se subirán (o se intentarán subir) en el siguiente `git push`

Imagina por ejemplo el escenario de la figura (creado usando [esta web](https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/#free-remote))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la caja de fondo gris a la derecha tienes el estado del repositorio remoto (por ejemplo, en Github o Bitbucket). En la zona blanca tienes el estado de tu repositorio local.

Como ves, en el local hay una "marca" llamada `origin/master` que se actualizó la última vez que hiciste push o pull del remoto, y que marca "por donde iba el remoto" en ese momento. Si nadie más actúa sobre el remoto, seguirá así (como de hecho ocurre en la figura). En aquel momento, en local, la referencia "master" y la referencia "HEAD" apuntaban ambas al mismo commit, el `9cc3325`. Ese commit es el úlitmo que hay en el remoto.

Pero después, en el local, has hecho unos cuantos commits más a partir de ese punto, por lo que la referencia "master" y "HEAD" han ido avanzando, dejando atrás la marca "origin/master".

Pues bien, `git log origin..HEAD` te da la lista de commits que existen entre la referencia "origin/master" y la referencia "HEAD" (ambas locales, este comando no hace conexiones a internet para ver cómo está realmente el "origin" remoto).

Como ves, lo que te está dando es la lista de commits que has añadido localmente desde la última vez que sincronizaste con el remoto. Por tanto esos serían los commits que se subirían ahora si hicieras `git push`.